# parsing file to gather section headers with subsequent content

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.x, text-processing

I need to merge the lines (in capitals) of my input file into one line as shown below:

**file1-inp**

```
=4455
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCC
=3433
GGGGGGGGGGGG
DDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEE
=44543
FFFFFFFFFFFFF
HHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

**expected output**

```
=4455
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCC
=3433
GGGGGGGGGGGGDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEE
=44543
FFFFFFFFFFFFFHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

**my code**

```
fp=open("file1","r")
a=[]
for line in fp:
    if line[0]=="=":
        print line.strip()
        print "".join(a)
        a=[]
    else:
        a.append(line.strip())
```

**Actual output**

```
=4455

=3433
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCC
=44543
GGGGGGGGGGGGDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEE
```

I know its quite silly, but can anyone please help me fix the problem in my code?

Comment: Is this the whole code? I'm getting `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

Comment: The problem is that if `a` is empty, `print "".join(a)` will still output a newline.

Comment: The other problem is that `print "".join(a)` will print the contents of `a`, which at the time contains all the lines from the _previous_ section of the file, not the section whose header you just detected.

Comment: @Kevin if i remove that line "a=[]"  then a will keep on appending all the lines in capital

`=4455 

=3433 
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCC
=44543 
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGGGGGDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEE`

Comment: @diablo8226: I would suggest only printing `a` if it is not empty.

Comment: It's not clear why `CCCCC...` isn't joined onto `BBBBB...`, but `EEEEE...` **is** joined onto `DDDDD...`  and which part of the attempted code addresses this variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate approach that may be easier to read and maintain if the logic grows more complex -- build a dict during the for loop, then print (or whatever other logic) afterwards:

```
fp=open("file1","r")
mydict = {}

for line in fp:
    if line[0]=="=":
        key = line.strip()
    else:
        mydict.setdefault(key,[]).append(line.strip())

for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    print key
    print "".join(value)
```

**Worth noting:** This approach will (may) affect the order of the sections during output, since the standard Python dict does not guarantee the order of the keys. If you're using Python 2.7 or greater, you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead, which does persist the order in which the keys were first inserted, and is a subclass of dict so it can be swapped in seamlessly.

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that the dictionary approach will change the order of the output (and why), now that I think about it ...

Comment: `OrderedDict`, perhaps?

Comment: Precisely. Thanks for the catch. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're printing `"".join(a)` after `line.strip()`, not before. Fixed version:

```
a = []
fp=open("file1","r")
for line in fp:
    if line[0]=="=":
        if a:  #  prevent printing a blank line at the start
            print "".join(a)
        print line.strip()
        a=[]
    else:
        a.append(line.strip())
print "".join(a)
```

(with `a` intitialised before the loop, and the final contents of `a` printed afterwards).

Comment: to avoid blank line, use : `if a: print "".join(a)`

Comment: @sfk yeah, I was just thinking that myself :-) Fix added.

Comment: You might also make it slightly more elegant by building a dict during the for loop, then printing at the end. Perhaps set `key = line.strip()` when `line[0]=="="`, else `mydict.getdefault(key,[]).append(line.strip())` ... the main benefit would be readability, and stability if you need to make the logic more complex.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn agreed - this answer focuses on fixing the error in the code that exists, but another answer along the lines you suggest would be worthwhile. If you write it, I'll upvote it ...

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Fair enough, I was writing the same thing you posted as well. :-) Just figured it's worth calling attention to the awkwardness implicit in the "backref"-style flow of printing the previous section each time a new section is started, then printing the final section after the loop ends.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of printing inside the loop, I'd just accumulate everything to be printed and output it at the end.  If you see a header line, append it and start accumulating lines.  When you see the next header, append the joined lines and the next header, etc.

```
with open('file1') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

out = []  # will accumulate lines to be output
items = []  # will accumulate lines between headers

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()

    if not line:  # ignore blank lines
        continue

    if line.startswith('='): # new header, join the accumulated items
        if items:  # don't add a blank line if no lines were accumulated
            out.append(''.join(items))

        out.append(line)  # accumulate new header
        items = []

        continue

    items.append(line)  # accumulate non-header lines

if items:  # handle last accumulated items
    out.append(''.join(items))

print '\n'.join(out)  # out is now a list of header, joined lines, header...
```

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/)

```
@(repeat)
=@blah
@  (collect)
@lines
@  (until)
=@/.*/
@  (end)
@  (cat lines "")
@  (output)
=@blah
@lines
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr data.txr data
=4455
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC
=3433
GGGGGGGGGGGGDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEE
=44543
FFFFFFFFFFFFFHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

[TXR Lisp](http://nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-01450DA7):

```
$ txr -t '[mapcar cat-str (partition-by (opip first (= #\=)) (get-lines))]' < data
=4455
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC
=3433
GGGGGGGGGGGGDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEE
=44543
FFFFFFFFFFFFFHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Awk:

```
/=.*/   { printf("%s", out);
          blah = $0; line = ""; next }
        { line = line $0
          out = blah "\n" line "\n" }
END     { printf("%s", out); }
```

Run:

```
$ awk -f data.awk data
=4455
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC
=3433
GGGGGGGGGGGGDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEE
=44543
FFFFFFFFFFFFFHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```